# rails bootstrap popover click doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, click, popover

I'm trying to use the popover like in [twitter bootstrap example](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers), so when you click a button it appears, and when you click it it disappear.

I have in application.js

```
//= require bootstrap-tooltip.js
//= require bootstrap-popover.js
$(function () {
$('.popover-test').popover();
```

});

And in my view _fof.html.erb

```
<button class="popover-test" id="button1" data-content="Popover Content">
    <%= 'ciao' %>
</button>
```

But popover comes only on mouse over, and when I move on it disappear. 
Have I to implement the function on_click in js?

Comment: can you provide a JSFiddle...?

Answer (score 0):

By default popovers are triggered by mouseover, not by clicks. If you scroll down on the Bootstrap documentation web page that you linked to, you'll see a list of options, including how to set the trigger.

```
Name: trigger
Type: string
Default: 'click'
Description: how popover is triggered - click | hover | focus | manual
```

So calling it would be like this:

```
$('.popover-test').popover({target: "click"});
```

Comment: So why default: 'click' if it's not by default?

Comment: I've tried with '$('.popover-test').popover({target: "click"});' and also '$('.popover-test').popover({trigger: "click"});' but the behavior is the same

Comment: Ha you're right, I even said it was the default - not sure where my head was. No excuse for that. Upon further examination, my assumption is that it's not working as expected because it's a button, and things are messing up with that. Try adding a link or div with a `.popover-test` class and it should work. You can use Bootstrap to make your links look like buttons.

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/weuWk/249/) this is a working example, but adding trigger: "click" doesn't work